# How does SQL Server execute transact script? (Same question takes vastly different time to exec)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I work at a big company that has huge SQL scripts. This user complained that his script was slow and I started looking at it.
To find what was slow I broke the questions apart and did select-insert into Temp tables and then used the Temp tables in his actual question.

But, the end result is that the question executes much MUCH faster if I keep the temp tables.

```
All in one question: Just shy of 20 minutes.
My broken up question: A bit more than 2 minutes.
```

There is a significant difference.

Ok, so the entire script is 940 rows long and each individual question that I put in Temp tables is around 70-80 rows.

The result of my Temp table work is a question that looks like this:

```
with cte_A
as (
   select *
   from #Temp1
   union all
   select *
   from #Temp2
   union all
   select *
   from #Temp3)
   , cte_B
as (select *
    from #Temp4)
   , cte_C
as (select *
    from #Temp5)
   , OB_BL_NotOverdue
as (select *
    from #Temp6)
   , cte_D
as (select *
    from #Temp7)
   , cte_E
as (select *
    from #Temp8
    union all
    select *
    from #Temp9)

SQL question based on the above.
```

Now the original question had the full 70-80 row question in place of the `select * from #TempX` so the *only* difference is that in place of 70-80 rows SQL I execute that SQL before the question and do the `select *`.
Total run time (creating all Temp tables and running the question) is 2 minutes. So I do all the exact same work in both executions.

The server we're running on is SQL Server 2016 (so not latest version).

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server attempts to optimise your entire query without temp tables, and as its very complicated it struggles to get an optimate query plan. When you break it down you force it to produce a number of smaller query plans which are much easier to optimise. Also as soon as you start putting data into temp tables SQL Server knows exactly how many rows it is dealing with as opposed to having to guess based on statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `CTE` is nothing then better writing code and doing separation, but for the engine it is working like subquery.

So, if you put all the queries inside of `CTE` and if they are accessing the same tables it is possible to confuse SQL Engine and then this will increase the number of **I/O reads**.

So, once you stored these things separately in the `Temporary table` then data is stored in the memory of the SQL Server in `tempdb`. So, for SQL Engine it is almost always easier to read data from the memory and tempdb than choosing some specific plan to read efficiently data from the disk.

Comment: Thank you soo very much! I had no idea about that.

That really helped me understand the problem. Exactly what I needed!
Have a great day!